# Security problem when instantiating a class in intranet zone, .Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, intranet, code-access-security

I have a .Net 2.0 activex control that is embedded within an HTML page (in IE7).
I use javascript to modify its properties and call methods. All this is fine until I call a method that instantiates a class using Activator.CreateInstance(type). I receive the following message:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
>   ..
>   ..
>   The action that failed was: InheritanceDemand
>   The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.PermissionSet
>   The Zone of the assembly that failed was: Intranet

The class I'm trying to instantiate has a parm-less **public** constructor, and from what I've read, there should be no problem using reflection on types that are public anyway?

I've done a temporary fix by using the Microsoft .NET Framework Configuration utility, to modify the intranet trust to full. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2003/06/20/57023.aspx).

How can I modify the method, class, or the assembly to avoid having to configure the framework?

A few extra points:

- The activex control is compiled
  against .Net 2
- Its assembly is not strong named
- I'm not bothered about granting reflection permissions.

Thanks

**Update**

It turns out it wasn't reflection that was causing the problem, it was a call to TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes which threw a FileIOPermission security exception. I've fixed this with the following code:

```
Dim temp As New Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted)
temp.Assert()
// Get attributes
System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert()
```

Now, If I set up a code group assigned to the strong name of my assembly and set the permission set to *FullTrust*, everything is fine.
However, I can't seem to fine-tune it, it's either *FullTrust* or an exception is thrown (see below). Even the *Everything* permission set doesn't work.

Exception:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(Void* pModule, Void* pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(Module module, RuntimeMethodHandle ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Module decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.ReflectGetAttributes(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.ReflectedTypeData.GetAttributes()
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode.DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(Object component, Boolean noCustomTypeDesc)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(Object component)
... GetAttributes
...
The action that failed was: InheritanceDemand
The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.PermissionSet
The Zone of the assembly that failed was: Intranet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The class I'm trying to instantiate
>   has a parm-less public constructor,
>   and from what I've read, there should
>   be no problem using reflection on
>   types that are public anyway?

You shouldn't have a problem with invoking the constructor via reflection if both the class and the constructor are public.  However, a public constructor on a non-public class would still pose a problem.

That said, given that it is an inheritance demand that failed, it sounds like the actual problem might lie elsewhere.  What happens if you attempt to create a new instance of the class from your control code without using reflection?

Comment: Interesting. Your suspicions were correct, a normal instantiation failed as well. It's something to do with a call to TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes, which throws a FileIOPermission security exception. I'll dig into it further...

Comment: It sounds like you're running into a problem similar to that described at http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2008/01/14/issues-with-the-xmlserializer-in-medium-trust-environments.aspx.  If you're not sure what attribute is causing the problem, you might want to take a look at the type definition in Reflector (http://www.reflector.net/).

Comment: Right again. Although I'm not reading the UITypeEditor attribute, in reading the attribute I'm interested in, it's throwing a full trust required exception because of the existence of a UITypeEditor attribute on the same class. No idea why. Thanks for everyone's help. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I was using TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(component)(attributetype), which retrieves all attributes before filtering mine out. I've changed this to type.GetCustomAttributes(attributetype), False), which ensures that the UITypeEditor is not read.

Answer (score 2):

I would add the ReflectionPermission attribute to your AssemblyInfo.cs file for the assembly attempting to reflect into the other class, with a RequireMinimum SecurityAction.

However, be aware that all this will do is prevent your application from running in the Intranet zone, instead of running for a while, all seems fine, till the reflection happens. Asserting permissions does not mean they'll be granted, it just allows a program to "fail fast". You can demand a permission all you want; the whole basis of CAS is that it doesn't have to be granted to you.

In order to use reflection in your app or assembly, you must either provide sufficient evidence to run the assembly in a less-restrictive zone (by strongly signing it, for instance), or configure the framework to include ReflectionPermission in the Intranet permission set.

Lastly, be aware that the declarative CAS security model is largely deprecated in .NET Framework 4.0; if you try to migrate this code to .NET 4.0 at a later date you will have to change the way you assert permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I strongly sign the assembly, is that it, or do I need to make further changes? For instance, would I need to configure the framework to fully trust my signed assembly? This is all new to me btw.

Comment: Well, if you strongly sign it with anything other than Microsoft's strong name or ECMA's strong name, it'll still be in the Intranet zone by default. What you have to do is either save the assembly to your local computer and run it from there (so it comes from the My Computer Zone and gains full trust), or define a custom Permission Set for all computers, with criteria stating that code signed with your company's strong name falls into that zone and gets that permission set.